# Backing up AFP Shares from my FreeNAS server

Tags: amazon-s3, truenas, backup

I have chosen to use Amazon S3 to back up my AFP shares from my FreeNAS server. What is the best / most efficient (automated) way in which to get my data from the AFP shares to Amazon S3. I have around 40 AFP shares that will require backing up every week or so, most less than 100mb however 1 over that is around 450gb.

My issue lies with my lack of knowledge backing up tools. I know I want to use Amazon S3 as the storing location however don't know how my data will be uploaded. Has anyone else used Amazon S3 with FreeNAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://s3tools.org/s3tools lets you synchronize to your buckets and transfers only the data added / changed. It does not do incremental backups though. You could hoever create independent buckets and snyc your share in different (e.g. daily, weekly, monthly) intervals via cron.

As it's python, it should run on freenas

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will take a closer look at s3tools